# Java Generate SOAP Envelope

Tags: java, soap

i have the following method :

String[] getEmployeeDetails ( int employeeNumber );
 The assosiate request look like this :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:getEmployeeDetails
   xmlns:ns1="urn:MySoapServices">
   <param1 xsi:type="xsd:int">1016577</param1>
  </ns1:getEmployeeDetails>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

this example come from this link [http://www.soapuser.com/basics3.html][1]

I don't understand how they do to generate it programtically with java.
Please help !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically you need to use SAAJ API,  this is an API that use SOAPMessage and give you some objects and methods to create SOAP request programatically, you shouls see [this](http://java.boot.by/ocewsd6-guide/ch10s03.html#c10s3a) link for further reference. Also review the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhr.html) from Oracle, they give you some useful examples. For real example you could check this [link](https://github.com/koitoer/Web-Services/blob/master/jax-ws/src/main/java/com/koitoer/jax/ws/jaas/JAASExample.java)

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

// Retrieve different parts
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();

// Two ways to extract headers
SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();
soapHeader = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();

// Two ways to extract body
SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
soapBody = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();

// To add some element
SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
Name bodyName  = soapFactory.createName("getEmployeeDetails","ns1","urn:MySoapServices");
SOAPBodyElement purchaseLineItems = soapBody.addBodyElement(bodyName);
Name childName = soapFactory.createName("param1");
SOAPElement order = purchaseLineItems.addChildElement(childName);
order.addTextNode("1016577");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try this approach i think it  match to my need

Comment: Hi ! I try it and i can create my SoapMessage properly. now i want to insert  following : xsi:type="xsd:int"  for the <param1 namenspace. Any idea how to do it ? soapFactory don't have anny method that support the XMLtype. I search by google without succes

Comment: javax.xml.soap.Name is this correct name class? from saaj.jar

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the wsdl from the soap service (usually something like http://endpointurl?wsdl), and then use Apache CXF's wsdl2java utility to generate code with the -client parameter.  The generated code will do a lot of the work for you in terms of building a valid SOAP request and sending it to the endpoint, or if you just want to see how it works, you could follow the calls it makes into the CXF source and see how they're doing things.

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't have a wsdl file. i will try the approach from Koitoer

Comment: If the SOAP service you are calling is published on an app server, it is often the case that you can download the wsdl by just adding "?wsdl" to the end of the base endpoint url that you use to call the service.  Just FYI in case you're missing a chance to simply download a copy of the wsdl and avoid doing a lot of manual coding work.

Comment: Yes i know but this SOAP service don't have a wsdl that why i try to construct it myself to send it in the Http request. now i need to kwo how to put the constraint for the namespace  like xsi:type="xsd:int. I search for it and found  i have to use something like XMLType_INT. can you tell me please to use it ?  Thanks for help