# How create SOAP request using SAAJ API

Tags: java, soap, soap-client, saaj

I understand that I may be ask a trivial question, BUT was unable to properly create the required SOAP request format.

SOAP request of this kind

```html
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
         <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <SOAP:Body>
         <GetParameter xmlns="http://examples/2001">
   <request>
         <MonCode xmlns="http://newsite/mon">Latency</MonCode>
   <TimeFrom xmlns="http://newsite/mon">2016-10-26T11:00</TimeFrom>
   <TimeTo xmlns="http://newsite/mon">2016-10-26T12:00</TimeTo>
         </request>
   </GetParameter>
         </SOAP:Body>
         </SOAP:Envelope>
```

I try to create SOAP request using SAAJ API by Java.
I found some question:
[Java Generate SOAP Envelope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570086/java-generate-soap-envelope)

and 
[Working Soap client example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948927/working-soap-client-example)

BUT not understood, how create SOAP request for my event.

Please help to create SOAP request.

p.s. try this code

```
            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelop/");

        SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
        SOAPElement bodyElement = body.addChildElement("GetParameter");
        bodyElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://examples/2001");
        bodyElement = body.addChildElement("request");
        SOAPElement paramsElement = bodyElement.addChildElement("MonCode");
        paramsElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://newsite/mon");
        paramsElement.addTextNode("Latency");
        paramsElement = bodyElement.addChildElement("TimeFrom");
        paramsElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://newsite/mon");
        paramsElement.addTextNode("2016-10-26T11:00");
        paramsElement = bodyElement.addChildElement("TimeTo");
        paramsElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://newsite/mon");
        paramsElement.addTextNode("2016-10-26T12:00");
```

BUT in result get SOAP request without value "http://examples/2001" "http://newsite/mon".

```html
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelop/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <GetParameter xmlns=""/>
    <request>
      <MonCode xmlns="">Latency</MonCode>
      <TimeFrom xmlns="">2016-10-26T11:00</TimeFrom>
      <TimeTo xmlns="">2016-10-26T12:00</TimeTo>
    </request>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code solve task

```html
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

        // Retrieve different parts
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();

        soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

        // Two ways to extract headers
        //    SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();
        //    soapHeader = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();

        // Two ways to extract body
        SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
        soapBody = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();

        // To add some element

        SOAPElement GetParamter=soapBody.addBodyElement(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://examples/2001", "GetParamter"));
        GetParamter = GetParamter.addChildElement(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("request"));
        SOAPElement MonCode=GetParamter.addChildElement(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://newsite/mon", "MonCode"));
        MonCode.addTextNode("Latency");

        SOAPElement TimeFrom=GetParamter.addChildElement(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://newsite/mon", "TimeFrom"));
        TimeFrom.addTextNode("2016-10-26T11:00");

        SOAPElement TimeTo=GetParamter.addChildElement(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://newsite/mon", "TimeTo"));
        TimeTo.addTextNode("2016-10-26T12:00");
```

Answer (score 2):

my opinion using Java SAAJ not simple, not flexible for use

this solve is better

```html
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String addr = "http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx";
        String request = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:example=\"http://ws.cdyne.com/\"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body>\n" +
                "<example:VerifyEmail><example:email>mutantninja@gmail.com</example:email>\n" +
                "<example:LicenseKey>123</example:LicenseKey></example:VerifyEmail>\n" +
                "</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(addr);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(request.length()));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("SoapAction", "http://ws.cdyne.com/VerifyEmail");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        pw.write(request);
        pw.flush();

        try {
            connection.connect();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader rd = null;
        try {
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String line;
        String respond = "";
        try {
            respond = rd.readLine();
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
                respond = line;

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(respond);
    }
```